# Timed momentary switch modifier

Tags: digital-logic, timer, delay, multivibrator, analog-switch

I would like to design a circuit that adds a power off delay

1. What would you suggest, is it possible to solve that basing only on the circuits batteries? Modifier from the market uses own 9V power supply but I am thinking if a new circuit could share a power supply with the batteries.
2. If yes the timing should not depend on the supply voltage.
3. Also it should not be dependant on the polarity of the loads voltage. And it should not draw the battery quickly.

The setup could look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how [this earlier question of yours](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696152/a-circuit-that-temporarily-keeps-the-toy-on-after-pressing-the-button) does not provide an answer?

Comment: The proposed solution by Marcus has a problem that it works only once (after that I have to press the button again, and again to reset the circuit). Futhermore I am asking if it's possible to achive circuit powered only from toy's voltage so the management of the batteries would be easier. I am not enthusiast of NE555 circuit also.

Comment: I also analysed some existing solutions from @jonk like https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/497845/most-efficient-delay-circuit/498138#498138 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321260/time-delayed-deactivation-of-a-circuit/321390#321390 but it's probably not applicable in my case and I have no idea how to modify it so it would be polarity independant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A circuit that temporarily keeps the toy on after pressing the button](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/696152/a-circuit-that-temporarily-keeps-the-toy-on-after-pressing-the-button)

Comment: Please re-open.  I think the question IS about circuit design, and I have one ready to go.

Comment: Please re-open the question since it's different that my previous question and the circuit. Please let for anwers.

Comment: Please reduce this question to focus on the circuit design

Comment: I just saw your post about a monostable.  Great minds . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping a timer circuit running while in series with the toy's battery and the toy itself, with a low enough voltage drop such that the toy functions normally, almost certainly is not possible with standard components.  However, an external circuit that would run for over a year on a single 9 V battery is entirely doable.

The device you linked to has several functions.  Which of these do you want?  If it is just the simple button press extender, that is one CMOS gate package and a specialized optocoupler that is actually a small solid state relay (SSR).  Unlike a normal optocoupler, the SSR output stage is two MOSFETs in series that pass current in both directions.

In operation, the button press powers up a monostable circuit, the monostable drives the SSR, and the SSR switches power to both the toy and its own monostable circuit.  After the timer time, the monostable releases the SSR, which unpowers both the toy and itself.

There is no on/off switch on the timer box.  The only battery current during the off times is the leakage current through a CMOS gate and two ceramic capacitors.

This can be done with just two MOSFETs instead of a logic gate package, but you will get more accurate and repeatable operation and snappier on/off to the toy with Schmitt trigger gates.

If all of this sounds ok, then one question is what to do if the button is pressed again during the timer cycle - ignore or restart the 2 minutes?

If this sounds like it is within your skill set, schematic to follow.

Two thoughts.  First, a long R-C timer is not very accurate.  For better performance, an oscillator-divider such as the CD4060 can be more accurate because it uses a 8000x smaller timing capacitor, always a good thing.

Second, the part about the circuit switching power to itself might not be necessary,  The static current in a typical CMOS logic package is less than 1 uA.  Over one year, that is less than 10 mA-h, approx. 20% of the battery's capacity.  This reduces the circuit's complexity and body count.

UPDATE:

Here is a first pass at a complete circuit.  It looks like a lot of parts, but it is very straightforward:  Button - R-C Timer - Output (plus an additional blinker).

[image]

U1A and U1B form a classic, true monostable.  Once the button is pressed, more presses during the timing cycle have no affect; the cycle does not restart.  D1 protects the U1B inputs from a reverse-voltage spike at the end of the cycle.  While most power MOSFETs can handle -20 V on the gate, CMOS input stages cannot.

R2-C2 are the timing components.  The time period is a little less than 1 x R x C, depending on the U1B input threshold voltage.  A Schmitt trigger input stage has two thresholds, one a bit above Vcc/2 and one a bit below.  It is the upper one that matters in this circuit.  These are not tightly-controlled parameters, so your results will vary.

U2 is a small solid state relay in a DIP package.  It needs only 2 mA of LED current when operating, and is the only real current load on the battery.

U1D is a relaxation oscillator heartbeat display, just something to do with a spare gate.  Note that this circuit uses the charge built up in its timing capacitor C3 to light D1, so the circuit consumes less than 9 uA when running.  R3 and C3 can be adjusted for a different flash rate, but keep R3 at a high value to reduce the battery load.  If you don't want this feature, delete R3, C3, and D1, and ground both gate inputs.

An alternative to the heartbeat display is to add a visible LED in series with the U2 input.  This uses the U1 input current, so it is free in terms of battery life.  To do this, reduce R4 to 2.4 K or 2.2 K.

C1 is a decoupling capacitor and should be as close as possible to the U1 power pins, with short leads.

There is virtually zero static current when the timer is not running.  Both sides of C2 are at or very near GND so there is no leakage current.  Both sides of R3 are at or near Vcc so there is no almost zero current dribbling through the U2 input LED.  The worst offenders are C1 and C3.  Both should be ceramic types to reduce their combined leakage current to less than 1 uA.

Comment: I only want the button press extender. I don't actually have an idea to solve this with one CMOS gate. Thank you for clarifying about impossibility to do this without external power supply. Then the solution with additional power supply is fine.

Comment: Not one gate, one gate package (4 gates).

Comment: Could you please provide though one? 

Comment: Actually, this can be done with just one gate, but why waste the other three?  Also, it can be done with no gates and just two transistors, but the timing accuracy (percent-error matching the calculated value) would be less.

Comment: See the UPDATE.